# How to upload & download files using mule in Anypoint Studio using FTP connector?

Tags: ftp, mule, anypoint-studio

I tried using FTP connector and FileZilla FTP server (xampp).
Here is my flow code and output. In case when I'm using SFTP I'm getting output as "connection is closed by foreign host".

Configuration XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:sftp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sftp" xmlns:ftp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/ftp" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/ftp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/ftp/current/mule-ftp-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sftp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sftp/current/mule-sftp.xsd">
    <file:connector name="FileRead" readFromDirectory="D:\Data\input" autoDelete="false" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
    <ftp:connector name="FTP" pollingFrequency="1000" validateConnections="true" outputPattern="output.json" doc:name="FTP"/>
    <flow name="ftpFlow">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="D:\Data\input" connector-ref="FileRead" pollingFrequency="100000" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
        <ftp:outbound-endpoint host="127.0.0.1" port="14147" passive="true" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="FTP" connector-ref="FTP" outputPattern="output.json" password="kamal" path="/" user="kamal"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Console Output:

```
INFO  2018-03-01 13:00:07,218 [[ftp].FileRead.receiver.01] org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver: Lock obtained on file: D:\Data\input\example.json
INFO  2018-03-01 13:00:07,300 [[ftp].FTP.dispatcher.01] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising: 'FTP.dispatcher.145993108'. Object is: FtpMessageDispatcher
INFO  2018-03-01 13:00:07,305 [[ftp].FTP.dispatcher.01] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting: 'FTP.dispatcher.145993108'. Object is: FtpMessageDispatcher
ERROR 2018-03-01 13:01:12,866 [[ftp].FTP.dispatcher.01] org.mule.retry.notifiers.ConnectNotifier: Failed to connect/reconnect: EEFtpConnector
{
  name=FTP
  lifecycle=start
  this=608b1fd2
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[ftp]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}
. Root Exception was: Could not parse response code.
Server Reply: FZS
```

Answer (score 1):

Listening port of File Zilla was 21. Port 14147 is administration port.

Answer (score 1):

Use the little small groovy script provided in that.This should work .I just tested this and working as expected .Deleting can be done by autoDelete attribute or fileAge .Please let me know if this helps

```
<flow name="ftptestFlow">
    <ftp:inbound-endpoint host="hostname" port="port" path="path/filename" user="userid" password="password" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="FTP"/>
    <set-variable variableName="fileName" value="fileName" doc:name="fileName"/>
    <scripting:component doc:name="getFile">
        <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[new File(flowVars.fileName).getText('UTF-8')]]></scripting:script>
    </scripting:component>
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="path" outputPattern="filename" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
</flow>
```